# How can i Compare dates in php with different formats Y/m/d and Y/m/d H:M stored in a database?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a query like that:

```
$monitor = $db->query("SELECT * FROM event,  step WHERE step = idstep ");
$countquery = $monitor->rowCount();
if ($countquery == 0){
    echo "no records";
}else{
    echo "show records";
```

and i would like to be:

```
$today = ("Y/m/d");
$monitor = $db->query("SELECT * FROM event,  step WHERE step = idstep AND datastep = $today");
$countquery = $monitor->rowCount();
if ($countquery == 0){
    echo "no records";
}else{
    echo "show records";
```

In my database, datastep is stored like: Y/m/d H:M and when i compare the 2 dates i have no results.
i would like to not consider hours and minutes.
How can i compare the dates, without changing the field datastep in the database?
I would like to convert datastep in Y/m/d format.

Comment: Are you storing your dates as a `varchar` in the database? If so, change that immediately. Store dates as a `date` or `datetime` and this problem becomes a lot easier to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime` object.

```
$today = new DateTime("2014/07/31");
```

and the you can format it whatever you like:

```
$today->format("Y/m/d H:M");
```

But I think you could also use `DATE()` in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM event, step WHERE step = idstep AND DATE(datastep) = DATE('$today');
```

`DATE()` function in mysql will return only day, in this way `DATE('2014/07/31 12:00')` will be equal to `DATE('2014/07/31')`.

Comment: in this way DATE(datapasso) = DATE($data) doesn't work. I would like to not consider hours and minute stored in datastep

Comment: try with `DATE('$data')`